# How should I keep View state of fragment and nested fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have few main fragments that are replaced via activity's fragment manager. All of these main fragments have nested fragments inside and these are managed using child fragment manager.

I need to **retain screen state of widgets** (like scroll position, EditText value,...) of **nested fragments** when **navigating back from backstack**. I found on some else stackoverflow post saying that I should reuse created Views to accomplish that.

```
View view = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        // other initializations here
    } else {
        ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
    }
    return view;
}
```

I feel that it **ain't the best approach** and **it can be memory hungry** for bigger applications. I don't know the right solution since Android Guide provides only simple examples for fragments in it's [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html).

Comment: have you tried with `onSaveInstanceState()`?

Comment: Yes, I use them for entity ID, that is displayed in current main fragment. I don't know how to put state of widgets and nested fragments in there, so everything is displayed, but every view change is reverted when navigating back from backstack

Comment: you don't have to save the nested fragments, the fragment manager knows what fragments to display when it comes back, each fragment should take care of himself, whenever it is destroyed, in `onSaveInstanceState()` save whatever you think it is needed.

Comment: @bogdan How do I restore fragment manager's state when I recreate View?

Comment: When you recreate the view, it means that you are returning from somewhere and the bundle `savedInstanceState` is not null. The fragment manager is handled automatically by the system so you don't have to restore it, what you have to be careful is that if you had a fragment inflated before, it will be inflated automatically again, you don't have to create it again, you only have to set the variables to what you have saved in the bundle.

Comment: @bogdan So I won't keep old View in field to don't use unnecessary memory. In second call of `onCreateView` I will have automatically inflated View and `savedInstanceState` won't be null. What should I return from `onCreateView` in that case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30895/discussion-between-miro-and-bogdan)